# Electrical Code for wiring multiple outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle

Is there a code that states whether a pigtail is required for each outlet or if the second screw on each outlet can be used to continue current to the next outlet in the series?  Since the only connection is that thin metal clip I was wondering if that is considered a proper connection versus wiring a pigtail into the connection for each outlet so that all wires are interconnected at each box.

For what it's worth...if pig tailing, are Wago or similar push in connectors allowed or must it be an actual wirenut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Code requires that continuity of the ground wire (equipment ground) cannot depend on a device.

The Code also requires that the continuity of the neutral (grounded conductor) cannot depend on a device if you are using a multi-wire branch circuit (Two hot legs, a neutral, and ground).

The Code never requires the continuity of the hot leg to be continuous.

So, that means if you are not using a multiwire branch circuit then you can use the clamps on the devices for the hot and neutral. The ground would need to be pigtailed on every device but the end of the line. If using a MWBC then you would also have it pigtail the neutral on all devices but the end of the line.

Wago, Ideal, and other push-in connectors are UL listed for use and can be used for joints in an electrical installations. Or you can use wire nuts. The choice is yours.

Good luck and stay safe!

Answer (score 3):

The NEC simply indicates that any connectors or devices have to be listed for that use. Pigtails are not required or prohibited in general. Receptacles with multiple screws are listed for such a use, so you're good there. Similarly, Wago and other push-in connectors are listed for connecting two or more wires together, as are wirenuts - assuming you don't overfill them of course.

Comment: Just don't forget NEC 300.13 (B) which wants you to pigtail neutrals on multiwire branch circuits (shared neutral).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the screw or pigtail. I like pigtails because it makes it easier to pull the outlet but if at the max wire fill it may fit better going to the screws.